# Doesn't indicate results are capped at 5,000 results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

On SO when a search returns > 5,000 results it indicates the results have been capped a 5,000 by displaying the number of results as "5,000+"

On P.SE it only displays the "5,000" without the plus at the end. This lead be to believe there was only 5,000 non-closed questions on P.SE when searching on 'closed:0'.

Cosmetic issue, put I thought I'd raise it since it can cause confusion.

Comment: Checked that the trilogy all have the +, as well as askubuntu, math.SE and english.SE

Comment: This appears to be fixed now. Perhaps a mod could add a status-complete tag?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a font issue, since the code is identical, but apparently fixed one way or the other.